# DHCP-Hooks not running on start up

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have a small usb-over-ethernet network of RPiZs connected to a single RPi4. I am accessing the zeros through an ethernet connection on the RPi4, so they need to send packets going to my laptop through the RPi4.

I created a hook at `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/40-route` which is run by
`/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks`.

It looks like this

```
# /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/40-route                                             
ip route replace 10.0/16 dev usb0
ip route replace 169.254/16 dev usb0 via 10.0.11.1 metric 101
```

If I run `sudo sh /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks`, it makes the appropriate changes to my ip table.

However, I have to run it manually after every start up. Is there a way to get the hooks to run automatically? Or am I going about this completely wrong.

I feel this is on-topic for RPi SE because there is no other distribution that uses `dhcpcd` as its default network manager.

Comment: this is a Linux question, not a Raspberry Pi question ... it belongs at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Unfortunately, your question has been closed to new answers. I've submitted a request that it be re-opened, but that's probably a [long-shot](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/long+shot). Before I invest more time, can you [tell me if you've read this?](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd-run-hooks.8.en.html)

Comment: I've re-opened this, but you might want to demonstrate more definitely that it does not run, eg., by shimming in something like `date >> /tmp/run-hook.log; echo $reason >> /tmp/run-hook.log`.  Note that if it is running, it is probably executed a bunch of times in close succession, since you don't appear to have checked the context via the environment at all.

Comment: The meatier bits of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` might be useful too.

Comment: @goldilocks thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, I got pulled away from this project and only just managed to do some investigating. 

You are right, it runs a bunch of times when the dhcpcd service gets restarted. I printed the `$reason`, `$interface`, and `ip route` before and after the changes. I found that the ip table changes remains stable with my changes in every round except the second to last where no reason or interface is listed, but in the next/final run the ip table starts missing my changes. Last round is IPV4LL for usb0. Then the changes are gone once it is started.

Comment: I am going to keep investigating this. Thanks for pointers.

Comment: Correction. Emacs ~ files messed me up. The second to last which is NOCARRIER for wlan0 ends with the correct ip table, and the next/final which is IPV4LL starts to run `dhcpcd-run-hooks` but ends with changes. Something must be running after that which removes the changes.